# What's the equivalent of this in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('<span class="pictos">j</span>').prependTo('li');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  var e = document.createElement('span');
  e.className = 'pictos';
  e.appendChild(document.createTextNode('j'));
  li[i].insertBefore(e, li[i].firstChild);
}
```

[Working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/icamu5)

Answer (score 1):

What jQuery actually does is take the element and clone it for each parent it needs appending to which is a bit faster, like this:

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'pictos';
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('j'));

var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].insertBefore(span.cloneNode(true), lis[i].firstChild);
}​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/beFRM/).